# Counting the occurrences of string in Java using string.split()

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm new to Java. I thought I would write a program to count the occurrences of a character or a sequence of characters in a sentence. I wrote the following code. But I then saw there are some ready-made options available in Apache Commons.

Anyway, can you look at my code and say if there is any rookie mistake? I tested it for a couple of cases and it worked fine. I can think of one case where if the input is a big text file instead of a small sentence/paragraph, the `split()` function may end up being problematic since it has to handle a large variable. However this is my guess and would love to have your opinions.

```
private static void countCharInString() {
    //Get the sentence and the search keyword
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence\n");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputSentence = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nEnter the character to search for\n");
    String checkChar = in.nextLine();
    in.close();

    //Count the number of occurrences
    String[] splitSentence = inputSentence.split(checkChar);
    int countChar = splitSentence.length - 1;
    System.out.println("\nThe character/sequence of characters '" + checkChar + "' appear(s) '" + countChar + "' time(s).");
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Side comment: don't close `System.in`!

Comment: Note that you're using the word 'character' in the title, but in your question and code, you're actually searching for a String

Comment: @assylias, why do you say that? If I remove that line, I get "Resource leak: in not closed"

Comment: @coder_learner Because that closes the console input stream which is probably not a good idea: in a larger program, if you need to read from the console again somewhere else you will get an exception. So it is probably better to leave the console open. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

A flaw that I can immediately think of is that if your `inputSentence` only consists of a single occurrence of `checkChar`. In this case `split()` will return an empty array and your count will be -1 instead of 1.

An example interaction:

```
Enter a sentence

onlyme

Enter the character to search for

onlyme

The character/sequence of characters 'onlyme' appear(s) '-1' time(s).
```

A better way would be to use the `.indexOf()` method of `String` to count the occurrences like this:

```
while ((i = inputSentence.indexOf(checkChar, i)) != -1) {
    count++;
    i = i + checkChar.length();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of edge cases, `split()` is the wrong approach.

Instead, use `replaceAll()` to remove all *other* characters then use the `length()` of what's left to calculate the count:

```
int count = input.replaceAll(".*?(" + check + "|$)", "$1").length() / check.length();
```

FYI, the regex created (for example when `check = 'xyz'`), looks like `".*?(xyz|$)"`, which means "everything up to and including 'xyz' or end of input", and is replaced by the captured text (either `'xyz' or nothing if it's end of input). This leaves just a string of 0-n copies the check string. Then dividing by the length of check gives you the total.

To protect against the check being null or zero-length (causing a divide-by-zero error), code defensively like this:

```
int count = check == null || check.isEmpty() ? 0 : input.replaceAll(".*?(" + check + "|$)", "$1").length() / check.length();
```

Comment: This doesn't work because checkChar is a `String` in the code, so presumably it could be multiple characters. The title is slightly misleading.

Comment: @spinlok I missed that. I've edited my answer to cater for multiple characters. It's not so pretty any more, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

`split` is the wrong approach for a number of reasons:

- `String.split` takes a regular expression

  - Regular expressions have characters with special meanings, so you cannot use it for all characters (without escaping them). This requires an escaping function.
  - Performance `String.split` is optimized for single characters. If this were not the case, you would be creating and compiling a regular expression every time. Still, `String.split` creates one object for the `String[]` and one object for each `String` in it, every time that you call it. And you have no use for these objects; all you want to know is the count. Although a future all-knowing HotSpot compiler might be able to optimize that away, the current one does not - it is roughly 10 times as slow as simply counting characters as below.
  - It will not count correctly if you have repeating instances of your `checkChar`

A better approach is much simpler: just go and count the characters in the string that match your `checkChar`. If you think about the steps you need to take count characters, that's what you'd end up with by yourself:

```
public static int occurrences(String str, char checkChar) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0, l = str.length(); i < l; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == checkChar)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

If you want to count the occurrence of multiple characters, it becomes slightly tricker to write with some efficiency because you don't want to create a new substring every time.

```
public static int occurrences(String str, String checkChars) {
    int count = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    while ((offset = str.indexOf(checkChars, offset)) != -1) {
        offset += checkChars.length();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

That's still 10-12 times as fast to match a two-character string than `String.split()`

<sub>Warning: Performance timings are ballpark figures that depends on many circumstances. Since the difference is an order of magnitude, it's safe to say that `String.split` is slower in general. (Tests performed on jdk 1.8.0-b28 64-bit, using 10 million iterations, verified that results were stable and the same with and without `-Xcomp`, after performing tests 10 times in same JVM instances.)</sub>